# Trying to make a randomly generated number guessing game

Tags: javascript, random

I'm supposed to make a random number guessing game.

So I know I need to randomly generate a number between 0 - 50, and the user needs to guess. Based on their guess I have to tell them if they're too low or too high.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do next. (Or if it's right.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Number Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 50...</h2>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <input id="txtInput" /><br>
    <button onClick="checkInput();genNum();">Is this your number?</button>
    <script src="js/main.js">
        var outputDiv = document.querySelector("#output");

        function checkInput() {
            var guess = parseInt(txtInput.value);
        }

        function genNum() {
            txtInput.value = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make use of javascript's `alert` or `console.log` for debugging. We're not here to write your code.

Comment: Why are you doing a `genNum` every time the user makes a guess?

Comment: I don't want anybody to write my code, I just want to know if it's wrong so far. I thought I needed the genNum to generate the random number that they're supposed to be guessing. Like I said, not exactly sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you cannot call two functions within one "onclick". You should create a function which calls the two functions and use that as your "onclick" function. Here is something to get you started:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Number Game</title>
  </head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <body>

     <script>

        function theGuess() {
            var guess = $('#txtInput').val();

            return(Number(guess))

        };


        function highLow() {
            // Generate a random number that is between 0 to 50
            // Math.random() returns a random number between 0 and 1
            var rand = Number(Math.random()*50);
            var roundRand = Number(rand).toFixed(0);
            // store user's guess as a variable
            var userGuess = theGuess();
            // validate the guess
            if (userGuess > 50) {
                return($('#output').html('Please enter a number that is between 0 and 50'));
            } else if (isNaN(userGuess)){
                return($('#output').html('Please enter a number, not any other data type'));
            } 
            // check equality of the guess
            if (userGuess < roundRand){
                $('#output').html("Too Low!");
            } else if(userGuess > roundRand) {
                $('#output').html("Too High!");
            } else if(userGuess == roundRand)  {
                $('#output').html("You guessed it!!");
            }
        }
        // onclick function
        function answer() {
            theGuess();
            highLow();
        }
    </script>
    <h2>I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 50...</h2>

    <div id="output"></div>
    <input id="txtInput" />
      <br/>
    <button onclick="answer()">Is this your number?</button>


  </body>

</html>
```

You still have the joy of figuring out how to validate the input; how to check if the input is blank? :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are generating the number in the wrong place. You should do that as soon as the page loads and each time after the button has been clicked. Store the output of `genNum` in a variable outside of any functions; initialize a variable like `randomNum` right inside your script tags; `var randomNum = 0;`

You just need to get the value of the text field in `checkInput`.

Do so like this:

```
var guessBox = document.getElementById('txtInput')
var theGuess = parseInt(guessBox.value)
```

Then, use an `if` statement to determine if `theGuess` is higher or lower than `randomNum`. Use the `<` and `>` operators for that. Based on the condition, set the content of your output div like so: `outputDiv.innerHTML = 'Your value was (something) than the real value'`

After that, still in `checkInput`, reassign the randomNum variable to the output of `genNum`: `randNum = genNum()` (it is important to note that we did not use the `var` keyword again.

That should give you a good idea of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems...

1) The script element cannot have both src and body content, if you want to include a external js script use a separate `script` tag
2) On click of the button you need to generate the random number and check it against the value entered in the input

```js
var outputDiv = document.getElementById("output");
var txtInput = document.getElementById("txtInput");

function checkInput() {
  var guess = +txtInput.value, //convert the input value to number
    ran = genNum(); //generate a random number
  if (isNaN(guess)) { //if the entered value is not a numerical value
    outputDiv.innerHTML = 'Enter a number'
  } else if (guess == ran) { //if both values are same
    outputDiv.innerHTML = 'Correct'
  } else if (guess < ran) { //if we entered a lesser value
    outputDiv.innerHTML = 'Less:' + ran
  } else { //we entered a greater value
    outputDiv.innerHTML = 'More:' + ran
  }
}

function genNum() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
}
```

```html
<h2>I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 50...</h2>
<div id="output"></div>
<input id="txtInput" />
<br>
<button onClick="checkInput()">Is this your number?</button>
```

---

The script tags should be

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script>
    var outputDiv = document.querySelector("#output");

    function checkInput() {
        var guess = parseInt(txtInput.value);
    }

    function genNum() {
        txtInput.value = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this sounds like homework so lets try to figure out the steps required to achieve your game. Once you have the steps, translating that to html/js or any other programming language should be relatively easy with the help of Mr. Google.

```
1. Load: What do you need to be able to start a game?
    1.1 We need a secret random number
    1.2 We also need a way to let the user input his/her guess
    1.3 We need to let the user check if their guess is right
    1.4 We need a way to communicate the result to the user

2. Start: Lets play!
    2.1 The user types a number
    2.2 The user confirms the number and sends it to be checked
    2.3 The game checks if the number is equal to the secret number, if not continue at 2.4
        2.3.1 The game communicates to the user that his/her guess was correct!
    2.4 The game checks if the number is less than the secret number, if not continue at 2.5
        2.4.1 The game communicates to the user that his/her guess was too low
        2.4.2 The user tries another guess, continue at 2.1
    2.5 The number must be greater than the secret number
        2.5.1 The game communicates to the user that his/her guess was too high
        2.5.2 The user tries another guess, continue at 2.1

3. End: Want to play again?
    3.1 Restart
    3.2 Bye bye
```

Lets begin turning this into code

```
// 1. Load: What do you need to be able to start a game?
//     1.1 We need a secret random number in js
       var secretRandomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
//     1.2 We also need a way to let the user input his/her guess in html
       <input type="text" id="guess" />
//     1.3 We need to let the user check if their guess is right in html
       <button onclick="checkGuess();">Guess!</button> 
//     and in js
       function checkGuess(){
            ???
       }
//     1.4 We need a way to communicate the result to the user in html
       <div id="message"></div> 

// 2. Start: Lets play!
//     2.1 The user types a number
//     2.2 The user confirms the number and sends it to be checked (presses the Guess button)
       var guess = document.getElementById('guess').value;
//     2.3 The game checks if the number is equal to the secret number, if not continue at 2.4
           if (guess == secretRandomNumber){ 
//         2.3.1 The game communicates to the user that his/her guess was correct!
               document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
           }else
//     2.4 The game checks if the number is less than the secret number, if not continue at 2.5
           if (guess < secretRandomNumber){
//         2.4.1 The game communicates to the user that his/her guess was too low
//         2.4.2 The user tries another guess, continue at 2.1
               document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Too low, try again';
           }else{
//     2.5 The number must be greater than the secret number
//         2.5.1 The game communicates to the user that his/her guess was too high
//         2.5.2 The user tries another guess, continue at 2.1
               document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Too high, try again';
           }

// 3. End: Want to play again?
//     3.1 Restart - generate a new secret random number
//     3.2 Bye bye - close the page
```

Clean it up

```
    <input type="text" id="guess" />
    <button onclick="checkGuess();">Guess!</button>
    <div id="message"></div>
    <button onclick="generateSecretRandomNumber()">Restart</button>

    <script>
    var secretRandomNumber; // outside makes it available to other functions
    function generateSecretRandomNumber(){
       secretRandomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
    }

    function checkGuess(){
        var guess = document.getElementById('guess').value;
        if (guess == secretRandomNumber){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
        }else if (guess < secretRandomNumber){
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Too low, try again';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Too high, try again';
        }
    }

    // make sure we have a brand new secret number once the page loads
    generateSecretRandomNumber();
    </script>
```

Now you can plug it into a full html page and tweak the remaining parts, hope it helps :)